# CSS Sprite-sheet animation with Multiple Row Sprite-sheet

Tags: css, animation, sprite-sheet

I am trying to play a sprite animation with css using steps like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/

In this link he basically defines the frames like this:

`@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}`

The problem I am having is; my sprite sheet is 1309 x 910 with 30 frames. Each frame is 187 x 182. So as result, my sprite sheet is 7 frames in first 4 rows and 2 frame in the last row.

Can I do the same animation, like the animation on link above, with defining the frames myself? Or do I have to change the spritesheet and make it 1 row 30 frames (Result being 5610 x 182 sprite sheet)

Comment: what about: you set up a fiddle with your sprite and try?

Comment: @caramba I tried it myself in multiple ways but whatever I do it just plays the first row and ignores the other rows.

Comment: it would be easier to help if you set up a fiddle and show what you have tried. you can set more values on background-position:HERE; it's background-position:xpos ypos; (x=horizontal, y=vertical). so maybe try something like background-position:-20px -50px; and see what happens

Comment: @caramba http://jsfiddle.net/erkinyldz/D5r7d/1/ Here is the jsfiddle link. I tested it out different things none of them worked. Left it in a working position for 1 row. Let me know if you can do the multiple row. By the way, I added the animation using jquery, but if this system can be done I'll switch it to css.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS animations with Spritesheets in a grid image (not in a row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571983/css-animations-with-spritesheets-in-a-grid-image-not-in-a-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 1 row. [`Your`](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/) example uses [`steps`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transitions-20120403/#transition-timing-function-property) function. It use number of intervals from start to end. So if you have several rows in your sprite, height(rows) will not influence on width of one step (interval).

Comment: Do not be disheartened by this answer. It _is_ possible, using two simultaneous `steps()`'d `@keyframes`: one for looping through columns, the other for rows. stackoverflow.com/a/22575868/1489243 has done it, and explains it beautifully. And the technique is sometimes useful, due to a strange inability of Firefox to support images over 32766px in either dimension: support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973667.