# CSS animations with Spritesheets in a grid image (not in a row)

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a sprite image, and found this great example:

Blog: http://simurai.com/blog/2012/12/03/step-animation/ (has succumbed to linkrot).
Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20140208085706/http://simurai.com/blog/2012/12/03/step-animation/
Code Fiddle:  https://codepen.io/simurai/pen/tukwj

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/

> ```
> .hi {
> width: 50px;
> height: 72px;
> background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
>
> -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
>    -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
>     -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
>      -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
>         animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite; }
> ```
>
> @-webkit-keyframes play {    from { background-position:    0px; }
>        to { background-position: -500px; } }
>
> @-moz-keyframes play {    from { background-position:    0px; }
>        to { background-position: -500px; } }
>
> @-ms-keyframes play {    from { background-position:    0px; }
>        to { background-position: -500px; } }
>
> @-o-keyframes play {    from { background-position:    0px; }
>        to { background-position: -500px; } }
>
> @keyframes play {    from { background-position:    0px; }
>        to { background-position: -500px; } }

I'd like to do the same thing, but using a square (power-or-two sized) image atlas instead of an animation strip.  For example, this one:

> [image: square image atlas]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since this can be a difficult to debug task, I would like to start with the same problem, but in an easier to debug environment.

I chose to do it as a rectangle animation over the full image.

```css
.hi {
    width: 320px;
    height: 315px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjMscm.jpg");
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.hi:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 53px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    -webkit-animation: playv 18s steps(6) infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes playv {
     0% { top:   0px; }
   100% { top: 315px; }
}

.hi:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 53px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 266px;
    top: 0px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    -webkit-animation: playh 3s steps(6) infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes playh {
     0% { left:   0px; }
   100% { left: 320px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">
</div>
```

Over the image, I display 2 pseudo elements, one is the row selector and the other the column selector. And I adjust the animations until they are ok

---

Now, lets verify that setting both animations at the same time works:

```css
.hi {
    width: 320px;
    height: 315px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjMscm.jpg");
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.hi:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 53px;
    height: 53px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    -webkit-animation: playv 18s steps(6) infinite, playh 3s steps(6) infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes playv {
     0% { top:   0px; }
   100% { top: 315px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playh {
     0% { left:   0px; }
   100% { left: 320px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">
</div>
```

---

And now the final project:

```css
.hi {
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjMscm.jpg");
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  -webkit-animation: playv 1s steps(6) infinite, playh 0.1667s steps(6) infinite;
  animation: playv 1s steps(6) infinite, playh 0.1667s steps(6) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes playv {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -315px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playh {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -320px;
  }
}

@keyframes playv {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -315px;
  }
}

@keyframes playh {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -320px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">
</div>
```

All this for a webkit browser, remove prefixes for IE and FF.
Also, in this approach it is imposible to avoid displaying the 2 blank images at the lower left corner. If you don't have a full grid, and don't want to display the empty images, you will need to specify all the keyframes one by one

Comment: could you please tell us how you can specify all the keyframes one by one?

Comment: This solution doesn't work in firefox, since this doesn't support `background-position-x` and `background-position-y`

Comment: Thank you for the good idea @vals. I only had empty frames which were showing the blank space. Also animation is different in explorer 11, any idea?

Comment: I noticed that all the styles where done with -webkit- prefixes. So IE would probably have problems. I have adapted the last snippet; it should work now.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer vals, the method is really nice

Comment: This is one of the nicest, most innovative, and best-explained answers on all of StackOverflow. And it’s a perfectly hidden gem.

Comment: Amazing answer with detailed tutorial. Thanks

Comment: Excellent answer, with practical example which helped me to achieve my target correctly... thank you so much for your experimental red moving grid... you are definitely very awesome programmer with great sense.

Comment: While your statement about blank tiles is true, just here to state the obvious to web searchers. It is often easier to simply duplicate existing frames in the image source so they are *not* blank; rather than define all keyframes

Comment: not all heroes wear capes

Answer (score 6):

Use background-position-x and background-position-y property instead.

For this image

[image: preview]

of size 710px × 355px

sprite frame size is 118.333px X 118.333px and we need to travel 6 frames horizontally and 3 frames vertically.

That means we need to create two separate keyframe animations to traverse each direction. When x direction animation is in play, other must froze until it completes.

Also duration of y animation must be 3X.

Here is code

```
<div class="hi"></div>


.hi {
  width: 118.333px;
  height: 118.333px;
  background-image: url("http://www.fore6.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/henson11-hp-1g.png");
  animation: playX 1s steps(6) infinite,
             playY 3s steps(3) infinite;
}

@keyframes playX {
  from {background-position-x: 0px;}
  to {background-position-x: -710px;}
}

@keyframes playY {
  from {background-position-y: 0px;}
  to {background-position-y: -355px;}
}
```

**[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2fw332gk/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for the cool example. I only have a different view of animation when opening in explorer 11. Any idea? It seems it dont animate either x or y coordinate. Thanks @Uday Hiwarale.

Answer (score 0):

To help understand how it works, here is a generic solution with SCSS in addition to the answer given by @vals : [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/jvanhouteghem/rkeyquzo/8/)

SCSS :

```
// Variables to edit
$imgUrl: 'https://mrbubblewand.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/magic_001.png';
$imageWidth: 960px;
$imageHeigth: 1152px;
$itemNbColumns: 5;
$itemNbLines: 6;
$spriteAnimationTime: 1s;


// =======================================

$squareWidth: $imageWidth / $itemNbColumns;
$squareHeigth: $imageHeigth / $itemNbLines;

// ========================================

.square {
    width: $squareWidth;
    height: $squareHeigth;
    background-image: url($imgUrl);
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px black;
    -webkit-animation: playvsquare $spriteAnimationTime*$itemNbColumns*$itemNbLines steps($itemNbLines) infinite, playhsquare $spriteAnimationTime*$itemNbColumns steps($itemNbColumns) infinite; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes playvsquare {
     0% { background-position-y:   0px; }
   100% { background-position-y: -$imageHeigth; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playhsquare {
     0% { background-position-x:   0px; }
   100% { background-position-x: -$imageWidth; }
}

// =======================================

.sprite {
    width: $imageWidth;
    height: $imageHeigth;
    background-image: url($imgUrl);
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.sprite:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: $squareHeigth; /* taille du carré */
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    -webkit-animation: playvsprite$spriteAnimationTime*$itemNbColumns*$itemNbLines steps($itemNbLines) infinite; 
}

.sprite:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: $squareWidth;
    height: 100%;
    left: $squareWidth;
    top: 0px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    -webkit-animation: playhsprite $spriteAnimationTime*$itemNbColumns steps($itemNbColumns) infinite; 
}

// Déplacement
@-webkit-keyframes playvsprite {
     0% { top:   0px; }
   100% { top: $imageHeigth; }
}
// Déplacement
@-webkit-keyframes playhsprite {
     0% { left:   0px; }
   100% { left: $imageWidth; }
}
```

HTML :

```
<p>Square :</p>
<div class="square"></div>
<p>Entire sprite :</p>
<div class="sprite"></div>
```