# Animating a spritesheet using css

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am having trouble animating a spritesheet using css 
every example i see contain a sprite sheet with only 1 line of sprite or 1 column 
like this :[image]

and they animate it using the `keyframes`

```
@keyframes play {
100% { background-position: -1900px; }
}
```

but for me the spritesheet is a grid with 10x8

Is their anyway to achieve an animation using css for this particular spritesheet ? or i should use HTML5 canvas instead ?

Every frame is 90x96 px

this is my image

[image]

Comment: there sure is a way, but calculating every position  might be more complicated than having them on 1 row or column

Comment: this spritesheet is done by texture packer , do you have an idea about texture packer of a way that i can align all those sprites in one row or column ?

Comment: AFAIK there should be a file .plist that stores positions and other options

Comment: as the accpeted answer suggests isent this a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571983/css-animations-with-spritesheets-in-a-grid-image-not-in-a-row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to handle an animation on grid sprites is to use 2 animations.
One for horizontal and one for vertical

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/Jg4f4/16/)

```
.hi {
    width: 90px;
    height: 96px;
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7o8R.jpg");
    -webkit-animation: playv 6s steps(7) infinite, playh 1s steps(9) infinite; 

}


@-webkit-keyframes playv {
     0% { background-position-y:   0px; }
   100% { background-position-y: 100%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes playh {
     0% { background-position-x:   0px; }
   100% { background-position-x: 100%; }
}
```

My answer is based on this answer:
[CSS animations with Spritesheets in a grid image (not in a row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571983/css-animations-with-spritesheets-in-a-grid-image-not-in-a-row)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, most KISS (keep it super simple) method I'd suggest is to take the image generated from texture packer, and copy and paste each row into just 1 long row, so you then have 1 long line. Save that as a new file to work from. More similar to the 1 line / 1 column example you have at the beginning.

I'd also suggest adding more padding/space between each fuzzball (best description I could think of) if possible. Otherwise targeting each frame with no bleed on the edge may be difficult. Such as row 9, column 9, with the fuzzball arms almost touching.