# Sprite PNG Javascript animation not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a Sprite animation using the following image:
[image]

To do so I am using it as a background and am trying to manipulate the background's position when animating. Somehow I can't get it working though - it shows the last frame from the very beginning.

Image: https://i.imgur.com/06vjVVj.png - 30800x1398 and 27 frames

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/magiix/pen/MWewdYo

```
#skull {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 1140px;
  height: 1398px;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/06vjVVj.png") 1140px 0;
}

const animateSkull = () => {
    const interval = 50;
    let pos = 30800 / 27;

    tID = setInterval(() => {
        document.getElementById("skull").style.backgroundPosition = `-${pos}px 0`;
        if (pos < 30800) {
            pos = pos + 1140;
        }
    }, interval);
};
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to animate it ?

Comment: @AmauryHanser How exactly do I animate it with css?

Comment: You need to create some keyframes `@keyframes bg {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: calc(1100px - 30800px) 0;
  }
}` then add the animation to your div `animation: bg 2s steps(27, end) forwards;`. (you need to get the position right though, I didn't check your spritesheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you check (with a console for example), you'll see that your `animateSkull` function is never called, because your `addEventListener` does not work. Change it to the following so it will be called (but your `animateSkull` function has another bug (or maybe your css I didn't checked) so it's not fully working after that but you should be able to fix that easily):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  animateSkull();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Actually it was solely a mistake inside of the codepen! Changed it to a click listener! You're right, the problem is CSS, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: You may try to change to a 100ms interval (50 is way to short) (your animation has 27 frames so 1s350 for the whole thing).

`const animateSkull = () => {
    const interval = 500;
    let pos = 0;

    tID = setInterval(() => {
        document.getElementById("skull").style.backgroundPosition = `-${pos}px 0`;
        if (pos < 30800)
            pos += 1140;
    }, interval);
};`

And your images in your background have not exactly the same size (30800/27px) so it slides slightly.

@Amaury Hanser is right it would be smoother with a css animation.

Comment: For the css animation version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047182/animating-a-spritesheet-using-css/29047769

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, but the frames in your sprite don't have the same width. So the animation looks buggy. (that is one huge image just for the animation)

```js
const animateSkull = () => {
  const interval = 1000;
  let pos = -1140;

  tID = setInterval(() => {
    if (pos > -30800) {
      pos -= 1140;
    }
    document.getElementById("skull").style.backgroundPosition = `${pos}px 0`;

  }, interval);
};
animateSkull();
```

```css
#skull {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 1140px;
  height: 1398px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/06vjVVj.png");
  background-position: -1140px 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

</style>
```

```html
<p id="skull"></p>
```