# How to target specific images within a div for animation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with multiple images inside a specific  element, and I want to create a JavaScript function that will animate these images. However, I'm having trouble targeting only the images within the div and excluding others on the page.

**HTML**

```
<div class="auto" style="max-width: 1050px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="/images/revital sub logo.png" style="width:550px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="/images/design.png" style="width:550px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="/images/Design4.png" style="width:550px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="/images/design2.png" style="width:550px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="/images/design6.png" style="width:550px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="/images/design5.png" style="width:550px">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 var index = 0;

 function changeBanner() {
   [].forEach.call(document.images, function(v, i) {
   document.images[i].hidden = i !== index;
 });
index = (index + 1) % document.images.length;
 }

 window.onload = function() {
   setInterval(changeBanner, 1000);
 };
```

I want to modify the JavaScript code so that only the images within the  are included in the animation. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you can select HTML elements according to various attributes, including ID, class, and tag name. Here are a few approaches:

Given that your images all have the class "mySlides", you can select them all with [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName).

```js
var index = 0;
const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('mySlides');

function changeBanner() {
  [].forEach.call(imgs, function(v, i) {
    imgs[i].hidden = i !== index;
  });
  index = (index + 1) % imgs.length;
}

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(changeBanner, 1000);
};
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/f55/000">
<div class="auto" style="max-width: 1050px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/90x90/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/70x70/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x60/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/aaa/fff">
</div>
```

Or, select all `<img>` elements inside the first element with class "auto" by chaining [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName).

```js
var index = 0;
const imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('auto')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');

function changeBanner() {
  [].forEach.call(imgs, function(v, i) {
    imgs[i].hidden = i !== index;
  });
  index = (index + 1) % imgs.length;
}

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(changeBanner, 1000);
};
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/f55/000">
<div class="auto" style="max-width: 1050px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/90x90/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/70x70/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x60/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/aaa/fff">
</div>
```

Similarly, you could use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
var index = 0;
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.auto img');

function changeBanner() {
  [].forEach.call(imgs, function(v, i) {
    imgs[i].hidden = i !== index;
  });
  index = (index + 1) % imgs.length;
}

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(changeBanner, 1000);
};
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/f55/000">
<div class="auto" style="max-width: 1050px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/90x90/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/80x80/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/70x70/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x60/aaa/fff">
  <img class="mySlides" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/aaa/fff">
</div>
```

Alternatively, [animate a sprite sheet with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047182/animating-a-spritesheet-using-css).