# How to animate something behind image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on my homework which is creating a simple web page with html, css and javascript. i was practicing on animating things with css, which I've found something cool on this [link](https://thunderpick.com/en/esports?list=upcoming) which it's making something move behind the image.

[Here's the thing it's moving behind Team Logo](https://thunderpick.com/assets/img/bolt/bolt.png)

Now I've tried to use the source page to find out how they managed to animate it, but still got no luck to understand it Since I'm still learning. is there any example base on what I've explained?

Comment: That's a "sprite sheet". It's a single image made up of "frames", and it's animated by only showing one part at a time and repositioning the image every few milliesconds. It's similar to a flipbook.

Comment: @TylerRoper How can i find a simple to make this happen? can u post an answer about it?

Comment: Unfortunately I believe your question is off-topic so I won't be submitting an answer (questions asking for off-site resources are not valid on StackOverflow), though you could start by searching "CSS Sprite Sheet animation" or something of that nature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS animations with Spritesheets in a grid image (not in a row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571983/css-animations-with-spritesheets-in-a-grid-image-not-in-a-row)

Comment: @TylerRoper well i did but it's kinda difficult because, looks like it's doing the animation base on lines, do u have any clue about which method i should search about? I've found rotate and some other moves, but this is kinda difficult . also thanks for guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22575868/3729184) answer. That's why I flagged your question as duplicate. It was cool and I couldn't resist doing it.

```css
.hi {
  width: 84px;
  height: 84px;
  background-image: url("https://thunderpick.com/assets/img/bolt/bolt.png");
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  animation: playv 1s steps(21) infinite, playh 0.0476s steps(3) infinite;
}

@keyframes playv {
  0% {
    background-position-y: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-y: -1764px;
  }
}

@keyframes playh {
  0% {
    background-position-x: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position-x: -252px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: black; width: 86px">
  <div class='hi'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what you doing is that first animating with playv then playh and u're setting positions base on width and height of image, right?

Comment: Also thanks for answer. i was messing with background-position, and was going to use -x -y base on what u linked in comment.

Comment: @Atlas-Pio yes exactly.

Comment: ah, then this is what i was messing before, because when u look at that image, it's feel like u should making some kind of ver~ / hor~ animation to make it work. also it is because i'm not experienced at this anyway... Well Thanks.