# Multiple CSS animations with 1 spritesheet in a non-perfect grid

Tags: css

I'm trying to animate my wiki, using the games spritesheets. I'm finding it difficult to find tutorials that allow me to animate different sprites on the same spritesheet, without having to put everything on the same axis. The all have differing step counts (2-5) and start at varying x and y-axis.

[I can't embed images yet, but here is a link to my spritesheet for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSdBY.png)

I found a wonderfully in-depth similar question<sup>1</sup> and answer but it seems to be slightly different in that it is 1 sprite spanning multiple columns and rows, and not multiple sprites spanning multiple columns and rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated so I can bring my Wiki to life!

<sup>1</sup>[CSS animations with Spritesheets in a grid image (not in a row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22571983/css-animations-with-spritesheets-in-a-grid-image-not-in-a-row)

Comment: If i understood correctly, if the sprites are scattered around the sprite sheet, you just have to tell it where is the next position to jump to in each iteration

Comment: @zohir I'm not sure how to do that when dealing with both the x and y axis.

Comment: Just like the question you posted the link tom you'll have to pre-divide the sprite sheet to know the position of each sprite

Comment: @zohik The example linked isn't any place close to where I need to be, unfortunately. **Dividing the spritesheet is exactly what I don't want to do.** Thanks.

Comment: Not divide the sprite sheet to separate sprite sheets, just visually to know where each sprite is

Comment: New to stackoverflow, and I don't mean to be rude, but why are you posting if you're unable to actually help? @zohir I'm posting here because I tinkered with the above example for 3+ hours without any success and have googled extensively to no avail.

Comment: I'm only giving you suggestions, because you didn't specify what you want exactly, and I don't necessarily have to write an answer if i can just put you on the right track